# what did I do wrong with java and sql database?

Tags: java, sql, derby

I'm trying to create a table with jdbc:derby database.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

public class DBCONNECT {

    Connection con;

    public DBCONNECT()
    {
        connect();
    }

    private void connect()
    {
        try {             
            con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:relative/db/dubbydata.db;create=true;","APP","");
            PreparedStatement st= con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM WF");
            ResultSet res=st.executeQuery();
            while(res.next()){}
            st.close();
            System.out.println("dubbyloop.DBCONNECT.connect()");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {          
            try { 
                 Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                 stmt.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE WF (FILEPATH CHAR(254) NOT NULL, FILESIZE LONG VARCHAR, WFDATA CLOB(2147483647), PRIMARY KEY (FILEPATH));");
                 System.out.println("CREATED");
            } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBCONNECT.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }

            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }



}
```

But i always get this error:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntaxfehler: Encountered ";" at line 1, column 118.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at myproject.DBCONNECT.connect(DBCONNECT.java:48)
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong. i changed everything in the create query.I removed the semikolon.i removed the size of the Clob or even the whole Clob.It doesn't matter what i do i get always the same error with no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Your try/catch strategy is incorrect. You should not be creating tables in JDBC. I would expect that the schema existed before the application started. Awful code.

Comment: Use `stmt.executeUpdate()` or `stmt.execute()` for DDL operations, instead of `stmt.executeQuery()`.

Comment: Making the assumption that you should create the table because the query failed may not be the best idea. You might want to look at [flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) to manage your schema. It works well with Derby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE WF ("
            + "FILEPATH VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, "
            + "FILESIZE LONG, "
            + "WFDATA CLOB(2147483647), "
            + "PRIMARY KEY (FILEPATH))");
```

There was one VARCHAR too much, semicolon not needed. CHAR is padded with blanks, so better VARCHAR.

And @MickMnemonic rightly mentioned one should call executeUpdate instead of executeQuery.

Comment: Does this really work in Derby -- creating tables through `executeQuery()`, which should be only used for `SELECT`s?

Comment: @MickMnemonic entirely right. I changed the answer; evidently it worked, though it should not.

Answer (score 0):

(comma before PRIMARY KEY, for example) ?
otherwise - general debugging strategy:
1) locate the line with erroneous sql statement (comment out one by one)
2) debug-print the resulting statement
3) check it against the target database

Comment: The comma before `primary key` is perfectly fine.